# How to get the type of the identifier at the cursor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I am writing an extension for Visual Studio 2012 that contains an ICompletionSourceProvider. I need to determine the type of the identifier at the location of the cursor. I tried the following approaches:

1. Using IClassifierAggregatorService, I am able to determine that the current word is an identifier, but there is no additional information.
2. Using DTE2, I can get a CodeElement at the current location, but the model is incomplete and the closest that I can get is the current method (CodeFunction)

It is obvious that Visual Studio has that information, but how can I retrieve it? I only need it to work when editing C# files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 offers no public API to access this information. We have it, yes, but you can't get to it. You might want to take a look at the [Roslyn CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), where we are working on a set of APIs to support scenarios exactly like your own.

Disclosure: I'm on the Roslyn team.